# Translating a node style from tikz to tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'd like to switch from tikz to tikz-cd to draw diagrams of arrows (I just started practicing, so I don't know much), and I can't figure out how to translate the following node style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[grade/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, 
             row sep=2.5em, column sep=3em,
             text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{\cdot &       \\
       & \cdot \\};
\path[->,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {$f$} (m-2-2)
        edge node[grade] {$[1]$} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried out some basic solution, but it just does't look right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\cdot \ar[dr,"f", "(1)" description, sloped, font=\tiny] & \\
& \cdot
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The main problems are:

- I can't figure out how to change the font size of the label;
- the labels overlap;
- the options affect both labels.

Plus it's very annoying not being able to type directly square brackets in the label.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two diagrams to compare:

[image]

The first diagram is the original one using a `matrix of math nodes`. The second one uses `tikz-cd`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\tikzset{
grade/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, 
             row sep=2.5em, column sep=3em,
             text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{\cdot &       \\
       & \cdot \\};
\path[->,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {$f$} (m-2-2)
        edge node[grade] {$[1]$} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=2.5em,
  column sep=3em,
  description/.append style={grade},
]
\cdot\ar[dr,phantom,"f" above right=1pt]\ar[dr,"{[1]}" description] & \\
& \cdot
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

To answer the specific questions at the end of the question:

- You can use `description/.style` or `description/.append style` to change the style for `description`. In particular, I used `description/.append style={grade}` in the second diagram.
- In the case of nested expressions with brackets, you need an extra pair of braces for the inner one, as in

  ```
  \ar[dr,"{[1]}" description];
  ```

  otherwise, the first `]` is considered the closing bracket for the opning one in `\ar[`.
- Instead of one arrow with two labels as in

  ```
  \ar[dr,"f", "(1)" description, sloped, font=\tiny]
  ```

  you can use two arrows; in this way, you have individual control over the elements:

  ```
  \ar[dr,phantom,"f" above right=1pt]\ar[dr,"{[1]}" description]
  ```

  since the first arrow is of style `phantom`, it isn't effectively drawn.
- You can use `left=<length>`, or `right=<length>` (or similar) to move labels. I used

  ```
  \ar[dr,"{f}" above right=1pt]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that using `\tikzcdset` the problem can be solved in an even more compact way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\tikzcdset{diagrams={row sep=2.5em, column sep=3em},
grade/.style={description,sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny}}
\newcommand{\gar}[1]{\ar[#1,phantom,"{[1]}" grade]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\cdot \ar[dr,"f"] \gar{dr} &       \\
                           & \cdot
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One has just to be careful and put `\gar` after the arrow, otherwise the label will be placed underneath the edge.